# Crear Label dinamicamente con Thread en WinForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito añadir labels dinamicamente desde un Thread en un WinForms y tengo el siguiente codigo y no funciona:

```
Label diskLabelInfo = new Label();
diskLabelInfo.Name = nombre;
diskLabelInfo.Location = new Point(339, LabelStartPositionY_Disk);
diskLabelInfo.Text = info;
diskLabelInfo.AutoSize = true;
this.Controls.Add(diskLabelInfo);
```

Comment: Por que debes hacerlo en un Thread?

Comment: @Pikoh Porque el Thread recibe una información cada x tiempo y tiene que ir poniendola

Comment: @Harman Si es así, entonces yo crearia un evento en el Form, que añada un Label al formulario con la información que le pases, y lo ejecutaria des del Thread

Comment: @Marc He creado una funcion para crear label y la llamo desde el Thread y tampoco va

Comment: Aunque así sea, todo lo relacionado con el UI lo normal es que se haga en el hilo principal. Lo que debes hacer es pasar los datos del hilo que recoje la informacion al hilo principal, y ahi crear el label

Comment: @Pikoh Y como hago eso?

Comment: Pues depende mucho de como lo tengas todo montado. Sin ver el código es difícil darte una solución. Igual es bueno que montes un [mcve] para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Puedes echar un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1314155) que tiene respuestas bastante completas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para modificar todo lo relacionado con el UI desde un hilo puedes usar [`Invoke()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

Por ejemplo, si intentamos crear un label y agregarlo desde otro hilo de la siguiente manera

```
Thread th = new Thread(() =>
{
   Label lbl = new Label
   {
       Text = "¡Dispara excepción!"
   };
   Controls.Add(lbl);
});
th.Start();
```

Se va a producir la siguiente excepción

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control '' desde un subproceso distinto
>   a aquel en que lo creó.'

Para evitar esta excepción, como decía antes, podemos usar [`Invoke()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), que lo que hará será

> <sup><sub>Segun mdsn:</sub></sup>
>   Ejecuta un delegado en el subproceso que posee el identificador de
>   ventana subyacente del control.

Por lo que podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
Thread th = new Thread(() =>
{
    Invoke((Delegate)new Action(() =>
    {
        Label lbl = new Label
        {
            Text = "¡No dispara ninguna excepción!"
        };
        Controls.Add(lbl);
    }));

});
th.Start();
```

y funcionaría correctamente.

Por último, en caso de tener una función, que no sabes si se ejecutará o no en el hilo principal, podes usar [`InvokeRequired`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeRequired);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) (es un booleano que te dirá si es necesario usar [`Invoke()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) o no)

Por lo que podrías hacer algo así

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke((Delegate) new Action(CrearLabel));
        else
            CrearLabel();
    });
    th.Start();
}

public void CrearLabel()
{
    Label lbl = new Label
    {
        Text = "¡No dispara ninguna excepción!"
    };
    Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```